# How to subtract one row from another row in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys I have two tables named `Requisition` and `RequisitionHistory` . The table `Requisition` is the main one in which has the unique entries are based on `RequisitionCode` (PK) but in table `RequisitionHistory` there are multiple rows based on `RequisitionCode` because each time any action (such as update etc) is performed on `Requisition` table, a new entry is inserted in `RequisitionHistory`.

This is my `Requisiton` table

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
| RequisitionCode | ApprovedCount | RequisitionDate    |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
|               1 |            10 | 02/01/2014         |
|               2 |            23 | 01/01/2014         |
|               3 |             3 | 02/01/2014         |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

This is my `RequisitionHistory` table

```
+------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| RequisitionHistoryCode | RequisitionCode | ApprovedCount | RequisitionDate |
+------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|                      1 |               1 |            14 | 01/01/2014      |
|                      2 |               1 |            10 | 02/01/2014      |
|                      3 |               2 |            23 | 01/01/2014      |
|                      4 |               3 |             1 | 01/01/2014      |
|                      5 |               3 |             3 | 02/01/2014      |
+------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

There are other columns as well in those tables, however for my query they are irrelevant thus they aren't included.

Now what I want to do is get the latest (based on `RequisitionDate`) `ApprovedCount` per each `RequisitionCode` from `RequisitionHistory`and then subtract it from `ApprovedCount` of the second last entry of the same `RequisitionCode` (there may be single or multiple entries of that `RequisitionCode` in `RequisitionHistory`)

What I tried to do (but failed miserably)

```
select RequisitionCode ,
(ISNULL((select top 1 ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory 
where RequisitionCode =r.RequisitionCode order by RequisitionDate desc),0)
-
ISNULL(
(select top 1 ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory where RequisitionCode
NOT IN 
(select top 1 ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory 
where RequisitionCode =r.RequisitionCode order by RequisitionDate desc) 
and RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode order by RequisitionDate DESC),0))
as StructureChange from Requisition r
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your "NOT IN" should be using RequisitionHistoryCode, since that is the PK of the history table.

Comment: You mean "WHERE RequisitionHistoryCode NOT IN...." ??? I tried it but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get when you try this:

```
select RequisitionCode ,
(
ISNULL((select top 1 ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory rh
where rh.RequisitionCode =r.RequisitionCode order by rh.RequisitionDate desc),0)
-
ISNULL(
(select top 1 ApprovedCount from RequisitionHistory rh1 where rh1.RequisitionHistoryCode
NOT IN 
  (select top 1 RequisitionHistoryCode from RequisitionHistory rh2 
    where rh2.RequisitionCode =r.RequisitionCode order by rh2.RequisitionDate desc) 
  and rh1.RequisitionCode = r.RequisitionCode order by rh1.RequisitionDate DESC),0))
as StructureChange 
from Requisition r
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you can do it in a slightly more readable way:

```
    WITH AprovalRecency AS (
    SELECT RequisitionCode, ApprovedCount, 
      RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY RequisitionCode 
                    ORDER BY RequisitionHistoryCode DESC) as Recency
    FROM RequisitionHistory 
    WHERE)
    SELECT r.*,  COALESCE(ar2.ApprovedCount, 0) - COALESCE(ar1.ApprovedCount, 0)
    FROM Requisition r LEFT JOIN 
     AprovalRecency ar1 ON r.RequisitionCode  = ar1.RequisitionCode 
                         AND ar1.Recency = 1 LEFT JOIN 
    AprovalRecency ar2 ON r.RequisitionCode  = ar2.RequisitionCode 
                         AND ar2.Recency = 2
```

.